# How to check if RawURL is nothing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to implement an if statement to check if the RawURL is nothing, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. This would only happen when they first load the page and it is just mysite.com. After initial load and navigation it will have pages for the RawURL like mysite.com/page1.aspx.

I am using ifs to check what the RawURL contains currently like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("default.aspx")
```

Comment: Surely you'd test like you would for anything else, i.e. `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl Is Nothing`.

Comment: That's what I tried, but when I went to the site with initially and had no RawURL it did not trigger the if. I'll do some more testing on it.

Comment: Ha, it actually isn't empty I guess since it contains a "/". Just changed it to = "/" and it works. Whoops.